# DevExpress TreeList - Show the tree outline in a column that is not the first

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

I am using the DevExpress TreeList in a .NET WinForms application to show hierarchical data.

The outline column (the one with the indents and the plus/minus buttons) is currently always the first column, even if the user moves columns around.

Is there any way to use a different column for this purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it off, but I don't think you can move it to a column another column from the first column on the left (whatever that happens to be at the time)

I am curious as to why you would want it in a different column...